# return not working on JS but console.log does

Tags: javascript

I was trying to set these to work for a simple if else, but return on 2nd argument in Else part doesnt return anything but if I use `console.log('Its not a string');} it works. Can someone enlighten me about it.

```js
let i = 'String';
console.log(i, 'is a ' + typeof i + '.');
//prints String is a string//

i = 100, typeof i;

if (i == 'string') {
  return ('Its a string.');
} else {
  return ('Its not a string.');
}
```

Comment: definetly interesting use of the comma operator.

Answer (score 2):

`return` (which is a statement, not a function, so the parenthesis are pointless here) passes data back to the *calling function*.

Your code isn't in a function. There is nowhere for it to be returned to.

For `return` to do anything you need to put it inside a function, call that function, and then do something with the return value.

```js
function example() {
  let i = 'String';
  console.log(i, 'is a ' + typeof i + '.');

  i = 100, typeof i;


  if (i == 'string') {
    return 'Its a string.';
  } else {
    return 'Its not a string.';
  }
}

let return_value = example();
document.body.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode(return_value)
);
```

Comment: Im sorry about my mistake, just got on javascript. literally days ago i was on HTML and CSS. tryin to figure things out. Thanks for the advise I'll try.

Comment: worth noting that `, typeof i` is superflouos.

Comment: I know, haha  I was messing up, just trying to see things out adn found that strange issue with my code. I know now why people had stackoverflow as a safehaven. works everytime

Comment: And now the comma operator tricked you. It's (i = 100), typeof i.

Comment: gonna study that body.appendChild things doesnt know that yet, but yeah, you  made it, so return as much as possible should be inside a function

Answer (score 0):

I guess you very new to programming. You need to learn more about functions, datatype, program flow etc.

what you are doing can be done like this:

```js
let i = 'String';
console.log(i, 'is a ' + typeof i + '.');
//prints String is a string//

i = 100;

if (typeof i == 'string') {
  console.log('Its a string.');
  }
else {
 console.log('Its not a string.');
  }
```

or you can do it like this:

```js
let i = 'String';
console.log(i, 'is a ' + typeof i + '.');
//prints String is a string//

i = 100;
console.log(isString(i));

function isString(i){
if (typeof i == 'string') {
  return('Its a string.');
  }
else {
 return('Its not a string.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Im on it right now. hopefully i will be able to get the stacks completely; as of now I'll have to learn a lot first. `isString(i)` what does this doe by the way since it on the console.

Comment: There are two parts here. First function isString() . You can see the function definition. Its fairly easy. IsString checks if the given value, i.e. one in the brackets, i is of type string or not. Based on this, it return one of the statement.  Second, console.log(), basically console.log prints whatever is inside the bracket in the terminal or browser console.. so here, console.log prints the value of isString(i) where i = 100